# Getting "date.timezone => no value => no value" after setting date.timezone to "Europe/Paris"

Tags: php, macos, symfony

### Description of the problem

I'm trying to set the date.timezone in my php.ini file (located in my /etc folder). I've done that and when I open it it clearly shows `date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"`, however when I check symfony system requirements it gives me an error (see screen shot) saying it's not set, and when I check my php information it says "no value" for date.timezone.

### Question

What is causing the date.timezone not to be updated?

### What I've tried and screen shots

My first guess was that I maybe I'm modifying the wrong file? but in the php -i I get:

```
/etc
```

[image: configuration file (php.ini)]

[image]

**/etc/php.ini :**

[image: php.ini]

**php < project name >/bin/symfony_requirements :**

Getting an error when I check for symfony requirements.

[image: symfony2 error]

**php -i :**

Getting 
    `date.timezone => no value => no value` when I check php information. why?

[image: php -i]

**`<?= phpinfo(); ?>`**

As you can see in the screenshot below, no there .ini files were found on the system.

[image: phpinfo()]

Comment: `php -i` from the command line will tell you the location of the php.ini files used from the command line.... if you want to find the `php.ini` file used by the web sapi, then run a script containing `<?php phpinfo();` from your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably two configuration files for CLI and for server.

So if you need to change timezones in both of them. To find location of php.ini file for your CLI use command:

`php -i | grep php\.ini`

for web location of php.ini I'd suggest using `<?= phpinfo() ?>`

You can also use (for example in Kernel file):

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Paris');
```

or

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
```

Moreover, check if you have `php.ini` instead of `php.ini.default`.

or

Make sure `/etc/php.ini` has the correct rights (ex: `sudo chmod 777 /etc/php.ini` ) , otherwise no value can be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Please check following path if you are use linux OS

```
vi /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

and change date.timezone then restart apache.. I hope your problem will be solve. Please let me know if you face issue

Or you can put code in your app_dev.php and app.php file which are located at web directory

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Paris');
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
```

Comment: How you know he is using Apache? Btw the webserver usually does not use the `cli` config.

Comment: Yes, You are right but try to change cli php configuration and check.. it's working I think

Comment: @AshokChitroda this path does not exist in mac.

Comment: enter command to get php.ini path php --ini you will get path then open it and change in .ini file

Comment: /etc/php.ini -> date.timezone = "Europe/Paris" and I have restarted my apache2 server. Still same error. If there is another php.ini file somewhere I am unable to find it.

Comment: leave it if you not find you can put in first line ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Paris'); date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris"); in your app_dev.php and app.php file which are located in web directory